# UDP Server stop receiving data

Tags: c++, c, networking, udp, server

I am trying to make a online simple game, when I test my game on localhost , there is no problem with the server and the client but when I try to connect my pc to my laptop over local network this start receiving data but few seconds after it stopped.

here is  my code:

[Server](http://pastebin.com/jvTeEMLj)
[Client](http://pastebin.com/Gvd8VxkE)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

Your problem probably is that UDP is *unreliable*, and that sockets by default are *blocking*.

So think about this situation:

1. Server is blocked in `recvfrom` waiting for a packet from the client
2. The client sends a packet, which is dropped and never reaches the server
3. The client goes on to it's own `recvfrom` call which blocks.

Now you have a deadlock as both the server *and* the client are blocked in `recvfrom`.

For a simple game like yours you might not need reliability, so it's okay if a packet here or there doesn't arrive. But what is important is that you don't block as then the deadlock situation might occur.

There are basically two solutions to this: The first is to make the sockets non-blocking, and handle the case where `recvfrom` doesn't receive anything. Take care here though, as your threads doesn't do any sleeping they will consume quite a lot of CPU power.

The second solution is to use polling like e.g. `select` to see when you can read from the socket.